# Is concatenated matrix multiplication faster than multiple non-concatenated matmul? If so, why?

Tags: tensorflow, matrix, lstm, pytorch, gpu

The definition of the LSTM cell involves 4 matrix multiplications with the input, and 4 matrix multiplications with the output. We can simplify the expression by using a single matrix multiply by concatenating 4 small matrices (now the matrix are 4 times larger).

My question is: does this improve the efficiency of the matrix multiplication? If so, why? Because we can put them in continuous memory? Or is it because of the conciseness of the code?

The number of items that we multipy doesn't change whether or not we concatenate the matrices. (Therefore complexity shouldn't change.) So I'm wondering why we would do this..

Here is an excerpt from pytorch doc of `torch.nn.LSTM(*args, **kwargs)`. `W_ii, W_if, W_ig, W_io` are concatenated.

```
weight_ih_l[k] – the learnable input-hidden weights of the \text{k}^{th}k 
th
  layer (W_ii|W_if|W_ig|W_io), of shape (4*hidden_size x input_size)

weight_hh_l[k] – the learnable hidden-hidden weights of the \text{k}^{th}k 
th
  layer (W_hi|W_hf|W_hg|W_ho), of shape (4*hidden_size x hidden_size)

bias_ih_l[k] – the learnable input-hidden bias of the \text{k}^{th}k 
th
  layer (b_ii|b_if|b_ig|b_io), of shape (4*hidden_size)

bias_hh_l[k] – the learnable hidden-hidden bias of the \text{k}^{th}k 
th
  layer (b_hi|b_hf|b_hg|b_ho), of shape (4*hidden_size)
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure of LSTM isn't about improving multiplication efficiency but more so for bypassing diminishing / exploding gradients (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/185639/how-does-lstm-prevent-the-vanishing-gradient-problem). There are some studies being done to mitigate the effects of diminishing gradients, and GRU / LSTM cells + peepholes are few attempts to mitigate that.

Comment: You didn't understand my question... I'm asking why we would *concatenate* parameters of LSTM for matmul.